# How to increase site ranking? for a keyword: Sushil Handa

Tags: seo, search, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I have a website located at: http://www.fifthvedaentrepreneurs.com

I am trying to get this website ranking as high as possible on Google with the Keyword "Sushil Handa" (promoter of the company). How do I do that? I am using various link building strategies but not very successfull so far.

Please share your ideas. Thanks in adavance for your kind co-operation.

Sincere Regards,

Sushil Handa

CEO - The Fifthveda Entrepreneurs

Comment: This question is way too much personalized for your business. It would be better, if you build this question as a community centric question.

Answer (score 0):

Few steps you can take here.

- Try putting the word "sushil Handa", on your much as much as possible. But do not place the word in the irrelevant way, or the advanced SE like google can detect this and will not index your link.
- Hire some guys, who will continuously find the page, from the site, from the site and keep on clicking them. <sub>Although, this might not be applicable for all the SEs</sub>

However, what you are trying to achieve is a very wrong solution to which there are many better alternatives?